# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No path information in request

Tags: struts-1

I'm migrating my current project from Struts 1.0 to Struts 1.3 and I'm getting this exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
"doFilter()"    "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No path information in request"    "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No path information in request
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.filter.RedirectionFilter.doFilter(RedirectionFilter.java:126)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No path information in request
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.SelectAction.getPath(SelectAction.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractSelectAction.execute(AbstractSelectAction.java:50)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Not so sure what you're expecting from us with this information...

Comment: Would like to know whether have u seen this error before when you do struts migraion